# fl.video.VideoPlayer loads flv relative to swf?

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3, video, flv

**Update:** Turns out this is [undocumented behaviour](http://www.blog.lessrain.com/path-problems-when-loading-flvs-into-netstream-object/) of the [NetStream](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html) class - NetStream loads relative to the swf, as opposed to URLRequest which loads relative to the HTML doc... annoying.

---

I am having a strange issue where loading an FLV file using the `fl.video.VideoPlayer` class that comes with CS4: [Adobe docs here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/fl/video/VideoPlayer.html)

Usually when loading external content into flashplayer, the path is relative to the HTML page that the swf is embedded in - but when I try and load an FLV using the VideoPlayer class the player looks for a path relative to the swf, not to the HTML (as you would expect).

eg:
My file setup is:
`index.html` (which contains the swf)
`swf/my-video-player.swf`
`video/my-video.flv`

When I call `videoPlayer.play("video/my-video.flv")`, from the swf (in index.html), the browser attempts to load `"swf/video/my-video.flv"`, which is relative to the swf, not to the HTML.

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour with the VideoPlayer class? Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: 'flash' being the popular one compared to cs4, might attract more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash "always" uses the html's path as the base for relative paths (more specificaly, all URLRequests)... This is unless the base html parameter is set ([see here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html#optional)).

However, I remember that when FileReference came out in AS2 (dunno about NetStream), for some reason its paths were always relative to the swf... when AS3 came out I think URLRequest fixed it.

I don't know which "VideoPlayer" class you refer to... a quick google search gives me a link to an AS2 class, so if you are using AS2 (bad tags BTW ^^) you might be running into the problem I mention.

And now that I think about it, NetStream doesn't use URLRequests (is it the only external loading process that doesnt?), so it might be related to that... maybe URLRequest.url gives a corrected url, I haven't tried it.

Comment: I'm using as3 - I've updated my question to include a link to the class docs.

Comment: As far as i can tell, fl.video.VideoPlayer uses a NetStream as its connection, so this might be the issue - I'll look in to it.

Comment: As mentioned in the update from the OP, the issue here is that NetStream has an undocumented bug; it always loads relative to the SWF, not the HTML, and BASE is ignored. Therefore, this answer is incorrect w/r/t NetStream due to this bug.